# How can i update a user password in docker container via bash script with the password as argument?

Tags: docker

When i run, via /bin/bash that takes in a variable,

```
docker exec -d <container> /bin/sh -c 'echo user:$1 | chpasswd'
```

sees that variable as empty.

I've tried setting it to an environment variable for /bin/sh to access but no luck.

Comment: You can do it in 2 steps `docker cp script.sh 12345:` and then `docker exec -it 12345 sh script.sh`

Comment: Got it working by doing it in 2 steps. Thank you so much.